# select id from post table where title=$title

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have post table and i have comment table i have made them with laravel
i made a IndexController and it has a method that returns all of my posts by their title;
i also return and compact comment of each post and show them under each post content but i have to pass the post id to comment table by myself
for example i have a post with id=7 and i have to pass the 7 to post_id column of comment table
i have to write a query something like this

```
select id from posts where title=$title
```

with this query i want to select post id by post title and pass it to post_id in my comment table

this my index controller

```
public function single($title)
{
    $posts = Post::where('title', $title)->get();

    $comments = Comment::where([
        ['post_id', 7],
        ['verify',1]
    ])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    return view('main.single', compact('posts', 'comments'));
}
```

this is comment controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Comment::create([
        'post_id' => $request['post_id'],
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'message' => $request['message'],
    ]);
}
```

and also this my single blade file code

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
            <div class="container">
                <div class="bg-secondary bg-opacity-10 p-3 mb-4">
                    <div>
                        <p class="fw-bold">{{$comment->user->first_name.' '.$comment->user->last_name}}
                            <br>
                            <span class="text-muted text-small-14 fw-light">{{$comment->created_at}}</span>
                        </p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="mt-0">

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {{$comment->message}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
```

and also i use laravel 8

Comment: What is your problem that you can't solve?

Comment: in Comment::where post_id i passed 7 by myself
i want to pass it by query to show each post comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following if you don't want to pass by yourself, assuming your relationships are correct. If not, feel free to include them in your current question, and I can help with those too.

```
public function single($title)
{
    $post = Post::with(['comments' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('verify', 1)->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }])->where('title', $title)->first();

    return view('main.single', compact('post'));
}
```

This will allow you to pass just a post to your blade view.

Now instead of

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
```

You can

```
@foreach($post->comments as $comment)
```